# importing CSS <link> property is not working on server

Tags: css, asp.net

I kept all my .css files in a folder . I am importing it on my aspx page
  . 
when I am running it on localhost it is working fine but when i am hosting it on server it is not working . When I am declaring  on each aspx page and rewriting the same css file it working fine . Now the question why it is not importing the file on server on localhost it is working fine .

Comment: The thing is it was working fine . But yesterday I deleted whole files and re uploaded all the new files . Now this is creating issue

Comment: Hi, can u provide an example how you are declaring your links, sometimes it happens that if don't put "/" before the closing ">" then it wont work.

Comment: my earlier code was <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/mybuton.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

Comment: But when I edited as DatScreamer said <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/mybuton.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> ... it worked =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with my hosting server not reaching the proper files even though they are imported successfully. What I did was backed up the files, deleted them and replaced them with the backup. I added ../ before all the folders in the links to get to the root folder, then I navigated to the css folder from there, and it worked. It may have something to do with the root dir being different. If it works great, if not oh well.

Answer (score 2):

To solve problems like this, we should use relative paths while specifying the url. We have faced the similar issues and it was because of not having relative paths. This [link](http://www.csstutorial.net/css_misc_inserting.php) may help you.  Please post your code snippet to help me understand further.

**To understand relative paths [click here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)**.

Comment: There are many other css files on that folder , but they are imported successfully

Comment: Okay. Could you check the url for the file that fails to import?

Comment: Please tell , if it fails to import should it work on localhost ?

Comment: Considering your latest comment on this question, maybe the file might not have been copied properly in the server.  If we are using relative paths in local that works fine,  it should be fine with the server.  Copying the files again could help.

Comment: Hi, I will be happy if I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a mismatch of the url, somehow it's not getting the file in the place it should. Try Rewriting the code again, sometimes it helps. 
If it doesn't work send the code.